# Уведомления от клиента к серверу (Push Service)

Tags: android, сервер

Передача данных с Android`a на сервер - не такая уж и сложная проблема.

А вот как передать информацию с сервера(сайта) на Android? Как они(смарфоны на Android`e) опознаются в сети(WI-FI или GPRS)?

Информация - самая простая(0 или 1).

Comment: периодически опрашивать сервер?

Comment: Грубо говоря, сервер не может передать прямо инфу, нужно знать точный адрес устройства, что есть редкость. Обычно делается так:
IP 19.19.19.1 или URL server.com/data )

- сервер передает данные по установленному соединению

Comment: А как быть, если сервер один, а устройств много, и передать надо на определенный? 
Пример: человек зашел на сайт, нажал на кнопку, и вся его инфа начала передаваться на устройство

Comment: дак пусть конкретное устройство и опрашивает, правда вам тогда надо внести систему а-ля регистрации. В простейшем случае хранить какой-то код в преференс, при первом обращении соответвенно запросить этот код, в дальнейшем использовать этот код

Comment: Значит на сайте должен быть код который занимается идентификацией пользователя и/или устройства и передачей ему данных. Например функционал занимающийся авторизацией по логину/паролю или через социальные сети.

Кстати, подробно опишите поставленную перед собой задачу, "передача данных с сайта" - очень широко толкуемая фраза.

Answer (score 5):

Для этих целей на Андроиде используют [Google Cloud Messaging for Android](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html).

> Google Cloud Messaging for Android (GCM) - это служба, которая позволяет передавать данные с вашего сервера на Android-устройство пользователей. Это может быть простое сообщение о наличии в вашем приложении новых данные, которые будут получены с сервера (например, фильм загруженный другом), или это может быть сообщение, содержащее до 4 КБ данных полезной нагрузки (так что приложения типа чатов смогут получать сообщение напрямую).

Comment: спасибо от меня)